# Kafka Docker CPU 100% after a restart

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apple-m1, bitnami

I am running Kafka and Zookeeper (bitnami) locally on my M1 Macbook in Docker using Docker Compose.  If I delete the data volumes for Kafka and Zookeeper and restart, it restarts perfectly and runs at a low CPU utilisation.

I have about 6 different consumer groups and 2 producers all running locally on the Mac that are different Node JS scripts.  Everything is great, until I stop the consumers, then shutdown and restart the docker containers (Ctrl-C to stop, followed by Docker Compose Up).

When I do that everything looks to restart fine, but the producers and consumers get Connection Refused errors (though sometimes connect, but don't stay connected).  There are no errors or warnings in the Kafka or Zookeeper logs, but when I look at the container for Kafka, Docker reports it is running at 100% CPU utilisation.  I can leave it for a stay and it will day at that utilisation level.

I can always resolve this by stopping the containers and deleting the volumes associated with Kafka and Zookeeper.  But, why is it doing this?  Why is it every time I stop and restart Kafka it gets stuck at 100% CPU?

These are the relevant portions of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper'
    pull_policy: always
    environment:
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: yes
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    volumes:
      - /Users/localuser/Documents/MintMonsterData/zookeeper:/bitnami/zookeeper
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    pull_policy: always
    image: 'bitnami/kafka'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '29092:29092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:29092
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: CLIENT
      KAFKA_CFG_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: 24
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
      KAFKA_CFG_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - /Users/localuser/Documents/MintMonsterData/kafka:/bitnami/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

Comment: Please read the description of the Docker tag.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it might be caused by the fact that Bitnami's docker images do not support arm64 architecture. See [the following issue on Bitnami GitHub](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/7305)